# C#/asp.net - Browser game, update player position for all connected clients

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

Here is a brief summary/context of where I'm at.  I am currently working on a game that will have many connected players at once.  The server is ASP.net/C# razor, and the front end runs in javascript.

At any given time, I need to know the x,y position of every player and transmit that the all connected players so that the client will update the browser.  What I have considered doing is that any time a player moves, I send their coordinates through an ajax call to the server, which will update the player object where I have an observer listening for dirty player states.

However, I am a bit lost on how to actually transmit this data to all of the other clients.  Also using an ajax call for this seems like it could be slow.

With all of this said,

1. What methods are available for sending data to connected clients over HTTP?  This a browser based game.  Would I need some kind of loop running on the client that is continuously requesting updates on all players? and if so, is there a cost-effective way of doing this without slowing everything down?
2. I've done some research into implementing some sort of server/client TCP socket connections, and using threading - but I read a few articles that threading was not the best solution for asp.net based applications.  I don't want to go down this rabbit trail if it doesn't really apply here.

Any information offered will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: *"What methods are available for sending data to connected clients over HTTP?"* - The particular name for the technology you're looking for is Web Sockets.  Specifically, SignalR may be the tool you're looking for.

Comment: Excellent! That looks to be exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr) will help you to do real-time web functionality by bi-directional communication between server and client.

Comment: You and David both answered the question.  Thank you for the information!